# invalid syntax: None, line 4, pos 72

Tags: python, date, space

I can't make a space between year and hour, and I am not allowed to use ",". I have use concatenation.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) + "/" + str(now.year), "+ "str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoiding such long statements and try format them in a readable way. You have wrongly put the `+` operator within `""` and I believe the `,` should be printed as a separator between *month/day/year* and *hour:minute:second*

```
print str(now.month) + "/" + 
      str(now.day) + "/" + 
      str(now.year) + " " +
      str(now.hour) + ":" + 
      str(now.minute) + ":" + 
      str(now.second)
```

Comment: It has to be written like mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss and using ","  counts as 2 print statements apparently

Comment: @Tobias Welcome on SO. This question has helped you and you accepted it. But you might +1 it additionally, if you want.

Comment: I believe he has to have at least 15 reputation for voting. Thanks for the +1 @glglgl. :)

Comment: @kocko Oups, forgot about that. Makes sense. Sorry for the confusion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 + str(now.year), "+ "str(now.hour) + ":"
```

Your `+` is in quotes and you have a comma after `str(now.year)`

Comment: Not allowed to use comma after (now.year) since it counts as two print statements

Answer (score 0):

```
now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y + %H:%M:%S')
```

type this command after 'now = datetime.now()' and you will get the output you want.